# Delete from one table using join on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables **doctor** with *doc_id* and *doc_name* and **patient** with *p_id* *doc_id* foreign key and *p_name*, and I want to delete all records from patients where it will match the doc_name='pardeep', here is my query

```
DELETE  FROM `doctor` , `patient`  WHERE
doctor.doc_id=patient.doc_id and doctor.doc_name='pardeep';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were **very** close. You have to tell what you delete first and then from what tables.

> **[`DELETE Syntax`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html)**
>   `DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]`
>   `tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...`
>   `FROM table_references`

Correct query might look like this

```
DELETE p
  FROM patient p JOIN doctor d 
    ON p.doc_id = d.doc_id
 WHERE d.doc_name = 'pardeep';
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35ed9/1)** demo

**On a side note:** consider using explicit ANSI `JOIN` syntax instead of implicit (coma) one.

Comment: :) yeah @peterm I got it now.

Answer (score 4):

you can just just an `IN` clause (or even  `=` ) with a subquery.

```
delete from patient where doc_id in 
 (select doc_id from doctor where doc_name = 'pardeep');
```

if you use `IN`, that mean that your subquery CAN return more than one result (so maybe more than one doc_id).

if you use `=` , your query will fail if the subquery returns more than one result.

Comment: Maybe you should warn the poser from the possible consequences of using IN instead of =

Comment: I got it, but I specially wanted to use joins.